# Arcpy Spatial Join Fails: Field is Not Nullable

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

We are working to perform a spatial join of a very large point .shp of voters (target_features) with another of incidents (join_features).

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, out_features, "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY")
```

is working on a small subset of the voters, but when run on the entire set, the error is:

```
Field is not nullable
```

for each of the fields in the incidents .shp.  Because this is Arc 10.2, we cannot AlterField_management or change the Nullability in Properties as seems possible in 10.3.  Instead, we copied the .shp features to a Default.gbd Feature Class (which now claims to have nullable fields in Properties) and re-ran it, but received the same error.

Is there another way to change or ignore the nullability of fields?

Comment: Shapefiles fields can't contain null field values. I'd suggest creating a feature class instead.

Comment: Yes, we did that to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to update the [field mappings](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/fieldmappings.htm) for your spatial join output. I'd iterate through fields and set those fields that are editable to `nullable`.

```
#target feature class
tFc = r"C:\temp\temp.gdb\target_featureclass"
#join feature class
jFc = r"C:\temp\temp.gdb\join_featureclass"


#list nullable fields for target feature class
tFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields (tFc)
           if f.type not in
           ["Geometry", "Guid", "OID", "Raster"]]

#list nullable fields for join feature class
jFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields (jFc)
           if f.type not in
           ["Geometry", "Guid", "OID", "Raster"]]


##target feature class
#create field mappings
fms = arcpy.FieldMappings ()
#iterate target fields
for field in arcpy.ListFields (tFc):
    #ignore shape/oid fields
    if field.type in ["Geometry", "OID"]:
        continue
    #create field map
    fm = arcpy.FieldMap ()
    #field name
    fieldName = field.name
    #add field to field map
    fm.addInputField (tFc, fieldName)
    #check if field name in nullable field list
    if fieldName in tFields:
        #set field to nullable
        field.isNullable = True
        #add output field to field map
        fm.outputField = field

    #add field map to field mappings
    fms.addFieldMap (fm)

##same for join feature class
for field in arcpy.ListFields (jFc):
    if field.type in ["Geometry", "OID"]:
        continue
    fm = arcpy.FieldMap ()
    fieldName = field.name
    fm.addInputField (jFc, fieldName)
    if fieldName in jFields:
        field.isNullable = True
        fm.outputField = field
    fms.addFieldMap (fm)

#perform spatial join with fieldmappings
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(tFc, jFc, out_features, "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY",
                           field_mapping = fms)
```